# Sorting by number of likes on page in confluence

Tags: sorting, confluence, atlassian-plugin-sdk

I am trying to sort the child pages of my confluence instance based on the number of likes to each child page of a parent page.

Example:
Page A as the root page.
Page B, C, D, E, F and so on are the child pages of page A. There is a sorting option to see the links of these pages on page A with default sorting alphabetically. What I like to achieve is to promote most liked page on top of the list.

Can someone help?

Regards

Comment: Have you found a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box Confluence doesn't have this feature at all and as far as I know, there is no third party plugins that sort pages base on popularity in page tree. You may come up with your own plugin for this feature as you can grab the most liked pages from database.

Comment: Exactly, I was wondering if someone could help me in getting the plugin or some changes in the code to get the desired result

Comment: Gotcha! I would say you may need to add confluence-plugin or confluence-sdk or even Atlassian-sdk tag into your question. But frankly speaking, I would say better to create a feature request for Atlassian. That way, there might be other users that come up with their workaround ;-)

Comment: I have created a feature request with atlasian. Although, I was expecting someone to help me some kind of hack that can help me achieve this. I know that confluence have a logic to track most popular pages based on likes and views, which they show on dashboard under popular content for a space. Though, my requirement is similar, its more related to {child} macro. can someone help please

Comment: Dashboard in Confluence works base on the indexes Ashish. And Page Tree that you are trying to sort is a bundled plugin. What you need to do is you have to customise that bundled macro to add a popular feature on it base on how Confluence read popular content in the dashboard. TBH I doubt that someone have the ready code for it and you need to start it from scratch :-) Just trying to be helpful and honest on it ;-)